# How to block Minecraft on pfSense?

Tags: pfsense

I am playing around with pfSense at home and I also installed the pfBlockerNG. My son is secretly playing Minecraft when he's supposed to doing online class. So I want to block the Minecraft client from connecting outside private or public Minecraft servers.  Any idea on howto? Thanks!

Comment: Unless your son is like 6 years old, this isn't a battle you're going to win.

Answer (score 2):

Like other posters said, most MC servers are on port 25565, but not all, and there are many ways children can innovate to workaround a simple port block.

However, if you'd like to test this, in pfSense go to Firewall > Rules > LAN. Click the Top Add button (green up arrow), then just choose the options:

1. Action: Block
2. Interface: LAN
3. Address Family: IPv4+IPv6
4. Protocol: TCP/UDP
5. Source: any
6. Destination: any
7. Port Range (only the first custom box): 25565
8. Description: Minecraft Port 25565 Styrofoam Vault Door

Save and reload your firewall

Comment: Yep, this works. I tested it. Thanks much!

Answer (score 0):

Just block the port 25565. Most servers are on that port.